# Creating 2 Models in Controller Action With Transaction - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

There are multiple answers that explain how you can have nested resources, however, my use case is a bit different.

Batches belong to orders and an order has many batches.

I can understand how it works if you have a form for an order and can create batches within that form, but cannot comprehend a good way for my situation.

I have a form for a nested resource (batch) where the parent (order) may or may not exist. They may select whether or not it exists via radio buttons. If it exists, they then just simply select which order it belongs to .. simple. If it doesn't exist, I show fields for the order and submit order params alongside of batch params. I want to make sure to rollback the order creation if the batch does not save.

Here is the code I have thus far.

```
def create
  @batch = Batch.new(batch_params)

  Batch.transaction do
    if params[:new_order] == "newOrder"
      @order = Order.new(order_params)
      @order.project_id = params[:batch][:project_id]
      begin
        @order.save!
      rescue
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
          format.json { render json: {order: @order.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          format.js { render json: {order: @order.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        return
      end
      #@batch.order_id = @order.id
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      begin
        @batch.save!
        format.html { redirect_to @batch, notice: 'Batch was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @batch }
        format.js { render json: @batch }
      rescue
        binding.pry
        raise ActiveRecord.Rollback
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: {batch: @batch.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js { render json: {batch: @batch.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This isn't behaving quite like I want it and seems quite ugly. I have a feeling I'm making it more difficult than I need to. What's the best approach in a situation like this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is a great opportunity to use a Service Object: https://www.engineyard.com/blog/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services .

This pattern is very useful for keeping Model and Controllers clean, and making sure those parts of the application are keeping to the Single Responsibility Principle.

What I would do in this case is create a service class called `CreateBatch` that takes in the parameters and performs the correct logic for each case. You can then render the correct output in the controller. This will also help clean up the conditionals and early returns you have.

For example:

```
# app/controllers/batches_controller.rb
def create
  project_id = params[:batch][:project_id]
  new_order = params[:new_order]

  result = CreateBatch.new(new_order, batch_params, order_params, project_id).call

  if result.errors
    # handle errors with correct format
  else
    # handle successful response with correct format
  end
end

# app/services/create_batch.rb
class CreateBatch

  def initialize(new_order, batch_params, order_params, project_id)
    @new_order = new_order
    @batch_params = batch_params
    @order_params = order_params
    @project_id = project_id
  end

  def call
    if new_order?
      create_new_order
    else
      add_batch_to_existing_order
    end
  end

  private

  def new_order?
    @new_order
  end

  def create_new_order
    order_params = @order_params.merge(project_id: @project_id)
    Order.save(order_params)
  end

  def add_batch_to_existing_order
    Batch.create(@batch_params)
  end
end
```

I did not run this so it may take a bit of tweaking to work, however, I hope it's a good starting point. One of the awesome things about this refactor is you now have 1 conditional for the logic and 1 conditional for the response, no need for adding in `Transaction` blocks, and no early returns. It may make sense to break the `call` method into 2 different methods that you can call from the controller. Using service classes like this makes the code much easier to unit test as well.

Comment: Thanks! This is interesting, I've never seen the convention before in a rails article. To me it seems like that would just be moving code elsewhere without much benefit; could you outline some of the benefits of this, please?

Comment: Sure! 1) Details about the data layer should not be a dependency in your controllers. 2) Your models should just be a thin layer over the database, without introducing additional business logic. Let's say anytime you want to create a batch you need to follow this same flow. In that case having it in a dedicated class whose jobs it is to ask these questions and process it correctly makes it easier to unit test this behavior, reuse it, and makes the other parts of your application simpler and single responsibility.

Comment: This is an interesting presentation from Gary Bernhardt highlighting some of these points - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUe6tacW3JE

Answer (score 1):

Why not move error handling and response rendering outside of the transaction?

```
def create
  @batch = Batch.new(batch_params)
  Batch.transaction do
    if params[:new_order] == "newOrder"
      @order = Order.new(order_params)
      @order.project_id = params[:batch][:project_id]
      @order.save!
      @batch.order_id = @order.id
      @batch.save!
    end
  end    
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @batch, notice: 'Batch was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @batch }
    format.js { render json: @batch }
  end
rescue StandardError => error
   @error = error
   format.html { render action: 'new' }
   format.json { render json: {error: @error, batch: @batch.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   format.js { render json: {error: @error, batch: @batch.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity  }
end
```

It's still quite complex, but it's definitely more readable. The next step would be to extract the whole transaction block to a service.

Comment: This looks much nicer. However, where do you catch any errors for the order creation?

Comment: On another note, do you think it would be worth it to completely swap out forms if they decide they need a new order and then have the form follow Rails convention of having the form for order, then nested attributes for the batch?

Comment: Yeah, it maybe  a good solution - you won't have to reimplement this logic in a controller. I'd probably do that in this case.